# CKEditor autolink is not working on typing URL but works on pasting URL

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using CKEditor with `autolink` plugin which is supposed to detect the URL but only working on pasting URL. When I type the URL its not linking. I am using CKEditor with `autolink`  plugin.
If it works only with paste, Can anybody suggest third party plugin that I can use to autolink urls?
Please look into this screenshot. I am using Chrome browser version 66.0.3359.181.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is how autolink plugin works.

Please see its code: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/major/plugins/autolink/plugin.js. This plugin only has `paste` listener. There are no `key` listeners which would convert typed text to link.

If you would like this plugin to be upgraded in the future, please report a feature request on CKSource page (perhaps CKSource will consider it): https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_howtos_bugs_and_features.html#how-do-i-request-new-ckeditor-features.

EDIT:
There is also a third-party plugin called [linkayt](http://https:ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/linkayt) in CKEDITOR add-ons repository however I have not used it, so I can't tell you whether it works fine or not. You will need to test it on your own.

Comment: did any body made a third party plugin for it?

Comment: There is https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/linkayt in CKEDITOR add-ons repository however I have not used it, so I can't tell you whether it works fine or not. You will need to test it on your own.

Comment: this one works for me.Can you add this to your answer please?

Comment: @Harsha Kakumanu, first of all sorry for not responding for so long. I have been away for a while. I have updated my answer as you have asked.